# How to Install firmware from Windows exe file?

Tags: linux, firmware

I want to apply certain firmware update. On PC vendor site it is available only for Windows in exe format. Via `fwupdmgr` update is available, however the version is not latest - about a year difference from exe one (according to accompanying exe txt file)

How to convert `exe` to format possible to install via `fwupdmgr`?

I've run:

```
$ fwupdmgr get-details file.exe
The input is not of cabinet format
```

Why "cabinet"? In [UEFI Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface):

> UEFI Capsule defines a Firmware-to-OS, modern and secure firmware
> update interface.[80] Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10[81] and Fwupd
> for Linux support the UEFI Capsule.

Is cabinet same as capsule or capsule uses cabinet format or...?

Comment: Why not make a bootable FreeDOS USB stick and use it to run the .exe file?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings, I've downloaded FD13-FullUSB [FD13-FullUSB].zip, added to Ventoy. On boot it displayed ""no bootfile found for UEI". As far as I've read update should be run in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

The link [Thunderbolt controller critical update for ThinkPad T480](https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-lenovo-thinkpad/issues/25) gives an example of how to substitute payload in Linux firmware update (LVFS) `cab` file with payload from `exe` and apply the update:

> HERE BE DRAGONS, YOU ARE ON YOUR OWN AND THERE IS NO WARRANTY:

> Some more notes during the update:

> - disable TB Assist mode in BIOS (though AssistTBT.bin may be the right firmware for TB Assist mode if you need it)
> - update BIOS/UEFI with fwupgdmgr, I got a new update today/few days ago and README of TB3 update says you should be on a current system firmware
> - download n24th09w.exe
> - you can extract this file with innoextract
> - as mentioned you are looking for TBT.bin
> - download the LVFS Update file for T480s as mentioned before as a template
> - this is a cab file, use something like cabextract to extract it
> - extract the update file, rename TBT.bin to firmware.bin, remove the signature firmware.bin.asc
> - change firmware.metainfo.xml line 6 to contain the GUID of the TB3 controller (Should be fe328c2d-5300-597b-a21d-991116db8ab6)
> - repack the cab file with lcab
> - install the resulting file with fwupdmgr
> - reboot for good measure

Or alternatively:

> You don't even need to create CAB files. You can flash firmware bin
> file directly into controller on your own risk:
>
> sudo /usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupdate -a
> XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX TBT.bin
>
> Replace XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX with GUID of your device.

I've tried to go former road, when checking `cab` file with `fwupdmgr get-details` I've understood that in `firmware.metainfo.xml` additionally to line `<firmware type="flashed"` with GUID I had to update below lines to pass the check:

```
<checksum type="sha1" filename="firmware.bin"
<checksum type="sha256" filename="firmware.bin"
<size type="installed" # size in bytes of firmware.bin
```

Contents of `firmware.jcat` can be extracted with `jcat-tool`, they were some PGP and PKCS7 data, no need to amend it to pass the check, also `firmware.bin.asc` which is to be deleted in the above instructions contains PGP too and can be left to be included in the cab file (check passes with it).